# Is it necessary to use Java synchronization on a field that might be modified by a single thread scheduler?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

I have a class (outter class) with the following

1. a List field to contain data
2. a getter method for the List field
3. a getDataFromDB method to return a List from online database
4. an inner class which implements Runnable and modifies the List field in its run method
5. in the initialize method of the outter class, a SingleThreadScheduledExecutor will be set up and it will schedule the inner class to run

I am wondering if it's necessary to put a synchronization block around where

1. the List field gets read in the getter method (2)
2. the List field gets modified in the run method of the inner class (which is a Runnable and will be scheduled by a SingleThreadScheduledExecutor) (4)

```java
public class OutterClass{

  private List<Data> data;
  private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

  @PostConstruct
  private void initialize(){
    scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new InnerClass(), // other configs);
  }

  private List<Data> getDataFromOnlineDB() {/* some work */}

  public synchronized List<Data> getData() { return data; }

  private class InnerClass implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      synchronized (OutterClass.this) {
        data = getDataFromOnlineDB();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question we need to know the intended access pattern to the managed data.

As written, your code handles an access pattern where the managed data is assigned at some point in time after the object is constructed, and where the managed data may be accessed at any point in time after the object is constructed, where the assignment happens in one thread and accesses occur from other threads.  Is that the access pattern which you intend to support?

Here is a smallish update to help clear up the code.  The only differences are syntactic rearrangements.  The function is exactly the same.

The main update which is to be noticed is that the assignment to 'data' is made in a setter.  That makes the synchronization quite a bit clearer.

```
public class OuterClass {

  // Some data to be managed.  Centralize all explicit references.
  private List<Data> data;
  public synchronized List<Data> getData() { return data; }
  public synchronized void setData(List<Data> data) { this.data = data; }

  // An executor used to launch code which asynchronously
  // compute and assigns the managed data.
  private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

  // Tie into this instance lifecycle by launching
  // a thread that computes and assigns managed data.
  @PostConstruct
  private void initialize(){
    scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new InnerClass(), // other configs);
  }

  // Code which computes the data ...
  private List<Data> getDataFromOnlineDB() {/* some work */}

  // A runnable used to asynchronously compute and assign the managed data.
  private class InnerClass implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setData( getDataFromOnlineDB() );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Making `getData()` method synchronized doesn't make the list synchronized, maybe [synchronizedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) should be used instead ?

Comment: That gets to the intent of the synchronization: Is the guard on reading and writing 'data' (ignoring that 'data' is a list), or is the intent to guard gets and puts on data as a list?  The code as written seems to operation on 'data' as a simple variable, in which case the synchronization is sufficient.  A synchronized collection would be necessary if code which retrieves 'data' is concurrently updating the list.